# Python - Combining two json objects

Tags: python, json

I am trying to follow the answer(s) in the question shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096554/combining-two-json-objects-in-to-one), but I'm still having some trouble combining my two json objects.

I have two JSON objects which are returned from a web call and I'm storing them in variables called: `likes_data` and `comments_data`. Each of these are currently empty JSON objects (in my test cases only) and when printed to the screen show: `{"data":[]}`.

Now I would like to combine these two (sometimes empty) JSON objects into a single object and print it to the screen, but I'm having some trouble because the final combined object always has escaped quotes in it.

The code:

```
data = { 'likes' : likes_data, 'comments' : comments_data }
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
```

results in:

```
{
  "likes": "{\"data\":[]}", 
  "comments": "{\"data\":[]}"
}
```

which is obviously an incorrectly formatted JSON response because of the escaped quotations.

Is there a proper way to combine two JSON objects in Python? for the simple case, I can manually unescape these, but I'd like to be able to manage "data" objects which are more complex.

Does anyone have any advice?

Cheers,
Brett

Comment: why not parse `likes_data` and `comments_data` and then put them into `data` as objects?

Comment: `JSON` is javascript object notation allowing data to be transmitted over a network or two different systems, it is transmitted as text and it is text to all other languages. You should convert json data to a python object and do your things, then encode it into json before you send; fee Fabian's example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
likes = json.loads(likes_data)
comments = json.loads(comments_data)
data = {'likes': likes['data'], 'comments': comments['data']}
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Like this?