# 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python

```
def participant_specific_donation(self, participant):
    donations = Donation.objects.filter(participant = participant)

    helper = {}

    for donation in donations:
        ##helper['donation_date'] = donation.date
        helper['donation_amount'] = donation.amount
    return helper

def participant_specific(request, participant):
helper = RelayFunctions()
info = helper.participant_specific_donation(participant)
info1 = helper.participant_specific_milestone(participant)

data = [ 'participant_specific_donation' : info , 'participant_specific_milestone' : info1 ]
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
response = json_serializer.serialize(data, ensure_ascii=False)
return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

Error:  'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'  Does this have to do with how I call the dictionary?  I wanted to combine two objects into an one.  Then parse it to json.

Here's the traceback.

```
Traceback:
 File "/home/vtrelayc/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
   111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "/home/vtrelayc/projects/relay/relayapp/views.py" in participant_specific
   192.     response = json_serializer.serialize(data, ensure_ascii=False)
 File "/home/vtrelayc/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py" in serialize
  98.     s.serialize(queryset, **options)
File "/home/vtrelayc/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py" in serialize
  46.             concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model

Exception Type: AttributeError at /participants/specific/1/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

def participant_specific(request, participant):
helper = RelayFunctions()
info = helper.participant_specific_donation(participant)
info1 = helper.participant_specific_milestone(participant)
data = [ 'participant_specific_donation' : info , 'participant_specific_milestone' : info1 ]
json_serializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")()
response = json_serializer.serialize(data, ensure_ascii=False) ...
return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: The `data = [ ...` line will yield a syntax error.

Comment: Is this the real code?
data = ['foo':bar] looks weird. Is this an array or a dict?

Comment: could you post your exact traceback, and the code around the location the traceback references?

Comment: t-8ch:    data = { 'obj1' : obj1, 'obj2' : obj2 }
json.dumps(data)  Came from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096554/combining-two-json-objects-in-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems that I see in the code snippet.

First, logical issue here :

```
for donation in donations:
    ##helper['donation_date'] = donation.date
    helper['donation_amount'] = donation.amount
```

If donations has multiple elements then you will end up with only the last element in the list, as you are looping over the `donations` and assigning the value every time to `helper`.

I think you want to calculate the total amount, which you can do as shown :

```
helper['donation_amount'] += donation.amount
```

Second, the line :

```
data = [ 
    'participant_specific_donation': info,
    'participant_specific_milestone': info1 
]
```

will give you a syntax error.

It appears that you need a dictionary over here. The correct way to intialize a dictionary is by using the `{ }` braces :

```
data = { 
    'participant_specific_donation': info, 
    'participant_specific_milestone': info1
}
```

---

If you want all the donations in a single place, you can make a list first :

```
donation_amount = [donation for donation in donations]
```

and then assign it to the helper dictionary :

```
helper['donation_amount'] = donation_amount
```

Comment: Thank you AshRj!!  Making that a dictionary works BUT I do want every element in 'donations'.  So I would make an array in a dictionary to do that?

Comment: I know this is 2 years old, but do you mean `donation_amounts = [donation.amount for donation in donations]`? Your list comprehension as written doesn't do anything but make a copy of `donations`.