# Receiving an error that my dict object has no attribute META in a Django app

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pull json data and display it on a page using Django. I am receiving the following error:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'META'

on line 36 of my views.py file which is the following:

> return render(request, 'base_generic.html', context=context)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793926/dict-object-has-no-attribute-meta) came up in a search but I have the correct brackets for my context and I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295448/how-to-solve-the-dict-object-has-no-attribute-meta) but it is honestly just confusing me even further.

Do you have any suggestions as to why this is happening or what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much and if there is anything else I can provide to make my question more clear I will do so. Thank you all for your time.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime

import requests


def index(request):

    request = requests.get(MY_URL_IS_HERE).json()

    current_temperature = request['currently']['temperature']
    current_cloud_cover = request['currently']['cloudCover']
    current_humidity = request['currently']['humidity']
    current_near_storm_distance = request['currently']['nearestStormDistance']
    current_near_storm_bearing = request['currently']['nearestStormBearing']
    current_precip_intensity = request['currently']['precipIntensity']
    current_uv_index = request['currently']['uvIndex']
    current_sunrise = datetime.fromtimestamp(request['daily']['data'][0]['sunriseTime'])
    current_sunset = datetime.fromtimestamp(request['daily']['data'][0]['sunsetTime'])

    test = 'test'

    context = {
        'current_temperature':current_temperature,
        'current_cloud_cover':current_cloud_cover,
        'current_humidity':current_humidity,
        'current_near_storm_distance':current_near_storm_distance,
        'current_near_storm_bearing':current_near_storm_bearing,
        'current_precip_intensity':current_precip_intensity,
        'current_uv_index':current_uv_index,
        'current_sunrise':current_sunrise,
        'current_sunset':current_sunset,
    }

    return render(request, 'base_generic.html', context=context)
```

**generic_base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  {% block title %}<title>weather</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <ul>
    <li><strong>current_cloud_cover:</strong> {{ current_cloud_cove }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_temperature:</strong> {{ current_temperature }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_humidity:</strong> {{ current_humidity }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_near_storm_distance:</strong> {{ current_near_storm_distance }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_near_storm_distance:</strong> {{ current_near_storm_distance }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_near_storm_bearing:</strong> {{ current_near_storm_bearing }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_precip_intensity:</strong> {{ current_precip_intensity }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_uv_index:</strong> {{ current_uv_index }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_sunrise:</strong> {{ current_sunrise }}</li>
    <li><strong>current_sunset:</strong> {{ current_sunset }}</li>
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Full traceback

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wx/
>
> Django Version: 2.2.3 Python Version: 3.6.8 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles'] Installed
>   Middleware: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/doug/Documents/opengarden/wx/views.py" in index
>     36.     return render(request, 'base_generic.html', context=context)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py"
>   in render
>     36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py"
>   in render_to_string
>     62.     return template.render(context, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     61.             return self.template.render(context)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     169.                 with context.bind_template(self):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in **enter**
>     81.             return next(self.gen)
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py"
>   in bind_template
>     246.             updates.update(processor(self.request))
>
> File
>   "/home/doug/.virtualenvs/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context_processors.py"
>   in debug
>     40.     if settings.DEBUG and request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR') in settings.INTERNAL_IPS:
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /wx/ Exception Value: 'dict' object
>   has no attribute 'META'

Comment: Use a different variable name here as it conflicts with the function argument: `request = requests.get(MY_URL_IS_HERE).json()`

Comment: @Selcuk wow. I have been searching for about two hours for an answer and that got rid of my problem. Now for some reason it's just showing a blank page and not my data but that's a new issue. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: You probably want to render `"index.html"` instead of `"base_generic.html"`

Comment: @GavinH You all are amazing. Crazy how I get so caught up and overlook such minor things. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was using the variable name "request" which was clashing with the function argument. It worked as soon as I changed that.

Thank you Selcuk and GavinH for your help.