# How to merge two ipython notebooks correctly without getting json error?

Tags: json, jupyter-notebook

I have tried:

```
cat file1.ipynb file2.ipynb > filecomplete.ipynb
```

since the notebooks are simply json files, but this gives me the error

```
Unreadable Notebook: Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '{\n "metadata": {'
```

I think these must be valid json files because file1 and file2 each load individually into nbviewer, and so I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096554/combining-two-json-objects-in-to-one/1096577#1096577

Answer (score 1):

This Python script concatenates all the notebooks named with a given `prefix` and present at the first level of a given `folder`. The resulting notebook is saved in the same folder under the name `"compil_" + prefix + ".ipynb"`.

```
import json
import os

folder = "slides"
prefix = "quiz"
paths = [os.path.join(folder, name) for name in os.listdir(folder) if name.startswith(prefix) and name.endswith(".ipynb")]
result = json.loads(open(paths.pop(0), "r").read())
for path in paths:
    result["worksheets"][0]["cells"].extend(json.loads(open(path, "r").read())["worksheets"][0]["cells"])
open(os.path.join(folder, "compil_%s.ipynb" % prefix), "w").write(json.dumps(result, indent = 1))
```

Warning: the metadata are those of the first notebook, and the cells those of the first worksheet only (which seems to contain all the cells, in my notebook at least).

Answer (score -1):

Concatenating 2 object with some properties does not always yield object with the same properties. Here is a sequence of increasing number : `4 8 15 16 23 42`, here is another one `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`. The concatenation of the two is not strictly increasing :`4 8 15 16 23 42 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`. Same goes for Json.

You need to load json file using json lib and do the merge you want to do yourself. I suppose you "just" want to concatenate the cells, but maybe you want to concatenate worksheet; maybe you want to merge metadata.