# How to automatically merge ipython notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am aiming to create live documentation for a project and I decided to use notebooks.

So far I have created a number of notebooks (one per chapter) and now I want to merge them into one and update it every time I change the individual ones. I also want to create a table of contents.

Is that possible?

Comment: you might be able to use the answer found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454668/how-to-merge-two-ipython-notebooks-correctly-without-getting-json-error)

Comment: Or have a look at this script: https://gist.github.com/fperez/e2bbc0a208e82e450f69

Comment: thank you guys but this seems a bit simpler than what I need. My notebooks have different kernels (probably should have mentioned it in the question) so merging them breaks in many ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work arround this by creating individual html and pdf versions of my notebooks and then use a python prost-processor(for the html) and pandoc(for the pdf) to merge them. The extra steps allowed me to remove any cells where not necessary in the final html and pdf documents.

If anyone needs it I can post the code too.

Comment: Can you post your version?

Answer (score 0):

Look at NBmerge.   You can merge notebooks with nbmerge.

https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge

You must install it with pip.  I just tried a `conda install nbmerge` but it failed because there's no conda package available at Continuum IO or conda-forge.  However it is a small utility so installing using pip install should not hurt your conda environment.

`pip install nbmerge`

and merge your files using the command.

`nbmerge file_1.ipynb file_2.ipynb file_3.ipynb > merged.ipynb`