# Convert JSON from Django to JavaScript Array and Loop to Populate 'users' Parameter in Mention.js

Tags: javascript, json, django, mention

I'm probably going about this all wrong, so I need some guidance. I'm using [`mention.js`](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js/) for linking profiles in posts in an application I'm building. Getting this working with hard coded data is trivial. Just set it up as described in the docs.

Well, for my app, each user who is logged in belongs to an organization, and this organization comes from Django as JSON. I want to populate the `mention.js` dropdown from which to choose with these data so when a user types, their organization list comes up. I have the JSON logged to the terminal console and browser console:

```
[
    {
        "fields": {
            "avatar": "images/avatars/bob.png", 
            "name": "Bob Jones"
    }, 
        "model": "accounts.profile", 
        "pk": 5
    }, 
    {
        "fields": {
            "avatar": "images/avatars/sam.png", 
            "name": "Sam Smith"
    }, 
        "model": "accounts.profile", 
        "pk": 7
    }
]
```

So I'm getting the correct data from Django. I can parse the data relatively easily and print to the browser console:

```
console.log(profile_array[0].fields.name);
```

The next step is to get this into the `mention.js` `users` parameter. Based on @sainaen's answer, I have this in my JavaScript:

```
users: profile_array.map(function (profile) {
    return {
        username: profile.fields.name, // this still missing
        name: profile.fields.name,
        image: '/media/' + profile.fields.avatar
    };
})
```

<s>The problem is that my profile does not have a `username` field. It's linked to the `User` model by a `OneToOne` relationship. So in my view, I'm actually returning two chunks of JSON: profiles (for `name` and `avatar`) and users (for `username`).</s>

<s>I realized that I can [combine these JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096554/combining-two-json-objects-in-to-one) and so I did that.</s>

<s>But now I'm having trouble getting the `username` out for the `users` parameter in `mention.js`.</s>

**UPDATE**

To solve this, I added a `username` field to my profile model. I added some code to a `save` override to autopopulate the`username` of the profile model to be equal to `user.username`. Not sure if this is the best method, but it allows for @sainaen's answer to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source of `mention.js` it looks like `users` is expected to be array of JS objects, so no function inside array will work. Also matching is performed on `username` fields and `name` is just for displaying results. So I think you should set not only `name`-s and `avatar`-s, but also `username`-s.

Idealy, if your Django model for user will contain `username`, it will look like this:

```
$("#some-field").mention({
    // other fields
    users: profile_array.map(function (profile) {
        return {
            username: profile.fields.username,
            name: profile.fields.name,
            avatar: profile.fields.avatar
        };
    })
 });
```

But of course, you could convert names into usernames by yourself on the JS side, with something like:

```
// converts names into usernames
// ex: 'Bob Jones' -> 'bob_jones'
function nameToUsername(name) {
   return name.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '_');
}
```

And then use it in code that creates `users` array:

```
$("#some-field").mention({
    // other fields
    users: profile_array.map(function (profile) {
        return {
            username: nameToUsername(profile.fields.name),
            name: profile.fields.name,
            avatar: profile.fields.avatar
        };
    })
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have it partially working, eg, with the profile. But you bring up a good point about the `username` field. I use a one to one mapping in my profile model, so it actually doesn't have a `username` field. It has a user field. I have edited my question with more details. Can you take a look and make any suggestions? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Well, you can use something else as a username, like login or email (probably, with the host part removed). AFAIK, `mention.js` requires for user to have some unique word-like identifier without spaces, I'm afraid I can't help much with that. So either you'll use some existing field as a `username` or generate it dynamically (on the client or server side) from other fields (like I suggested with the `nameToUsername()`).

Comment: The problem is the `username` is not a subset or substring of either `name` or `email` (so I can't derive them as you suggested). I have two JSON arrays representing two models and their fields. So I'm trying to get the `name` and the `avatar`from the profile object and the `username` from the user object. I edited my question to explain this. Dumping the two arrays in Python (`json.dumps()`) didn't work and I also tried concatenating them in JS, eg like (`profile_array.concat(user_array);`).