# How to merge two JSONs

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have two dicts like this:

```
array1=["1","2"]
array=[
       [{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"}],
       [{"c":"1"},{"d":"2"}]
     ]
```

I want to convert them to JSONs and then merge them like this:

```
json3=[
        "1": [{a:"1"},{b:"2"}],
        "2": [{c:"1"},{d:"2"}]        
  ]
```

I've converted them to JSON by `json.dumps()` and now I can't figure out how to merge them the way I want.

My question is somehow similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096554/combining-two-json-objects-in-to-one), but the results are different.

I tried this:

```
json3 = {key: value for (key, value) in (json1.items() + json2.items())}
```

But I get:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I tried some other ways but none of them worked how I wanted

```
dict_of_dicts = {i:d for i, d in zip(idJson, imgJson)} # Also didn't work
```

Comment: You need to `json.loads`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham And `json.dumps`

Comment: Why oh why are you posting something that looks like python lists when they are strings? Care to edit that?

Comment: @BhargavRao, not unless they want a string again ;)

Comment: @AlexJolig, you cannot have the format you want, you can have a dict or a list not a hybrid of both. What are  you doing with the json?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have to send it as a JSON to my `django` project when I'll read it by `AngularJS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library for that.

`json.loads` converts the json string to a dict. `json.dumps` recovers your json from the dict.

```
json1='["1","2"]'
json2='[[{"a":"1"},{"b":"2"}],[{"c":"1"},{"d":"2"}]]'
import json
j1 = json.loads(json1)
j2 = json.loads(json2)
j3 = dict(zip(j1, j2))
json3 =  json.dumps(j3)
```

The output will be

```
>>> json3
'{"1": [{"a": "1"}, {"b": "2"}], "2": [{"c": "1"}, {"d": "2"}]}'
```